# ECS mount volume to nginx container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up ECS in order to run my php/nginx docker application.

It works locally using this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
  services:

   nginx:
    image: NGINX-IMAGE
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - php
    environment:
        APP_SERVER_NAME: <ip>

   php:
    image: PHP-IMAGE
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes:
        - /var/www/html
```

The problem is that I can't get this working using ECS. 
I don't know how to create the web-data volume and let nginx grap it using `volumes_from`.

I am trying to create the volume using this JSON:

```
 volumes='[
   {
       "name": "webdata",
       "host": {
          "sourcePath": "/var/www/html"
       }
   }
 ]'
```

And then in my container-definitions to the php-container I add:

```
"mountPoints": 
 [
     {
       "sourceVolume": "webdata",
       "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
       "readOnly": false
     }
 ]
```

However, when I do this, it adds the content from the host's `/var/www/html` folder to the `/var/www/html` folder of the containers. 
My question is, how do I configure the volume to use the data from the php's `/var/www/html` container and let nginx access this data?

Comment: You will need to define same mountpoints for both the containers. `volume_from` is deprecated and should not be used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that suited the setup for ECS.
I simply created a VOLUME in my php Dockerfile referencing `/var/www/html`.

This means I longer need to reference the volume in the `volumes` section of the php container. And nginx will still be able to access the volume  with `volumes_from`.

*Update*

This is my working task definition for ECS:

```
task_template='[
{
  "name": "nginx",
  "image": "NGINX_IMAGE",
  "essential": true,
  "cpu": 10,
  "memoryReservation": 1000,
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": 80,
      "hostPort": 80
    }
  ],
  "environment" : [
      { "name" : "APP_SERVER_NAME", "value" : "%s" }
  ],
  "links": [
      "app"
  ],
  "volumesFrom": [
      { "sourceContainer": "app" }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "app",
  "image": "IMAGE",
  "essential": true,
  "cpu": 10,
  "memoryReservation": 1000,
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": 9000,
      "hostPort": 9000
    }
  ]
}
]'
```

And then I added `VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]` to my app Dockerfile. Now nginx can access the data with the `volumes_from` argument in the task definition.

Comment: Can you post the working example and steps to do? can not figure it out...

Comment: @user3315525 here you go, let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: can you have a look at my question pls [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855263/how-to-mount-volume-to-nginx-containerecs) I have a problem to mount volumes to the right place and also I need help to anderstand the image to the same image concept... Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thanks. These configurations will not work on ECS Fargate. Links are not supported when networkMode=awsvpc and that's the only network mode on Fargate now.